# vuejs nextick don't update

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, vue-router

i try to connect my frontend to my backend,
the request is done correctly i received the correct data, but the DOM is not updating. I use this.$nextTick but it doesn't affect the update

in the template i use {{ system.CPU.avgload }}
like i said the fetch is done correctly it pass into nexttick, but nothing change

in the main vue i have this

```
import System from '../utils/system'
import Auth from '../utils/auth'

export default {
  created: function () {
    this.system = {
      CPU: {
        avgload: 0
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.fetchData()
    setInterval(function () {
      this.fetchData()
    }.bind(this), 10000)
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      if (!Auth.checkAuth) {
        console.log('test')
        this.error = true
      } else {
        var self = this
        this.$nextTick(function () {
          System.Get(function (response) {
            self.system = response
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the template is

```
<div class="text-xs-left" id="example-caption-1">CPU : {{ system.CPU.avgload }} %</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add variable `system` in the [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) section of vue instance. Than only this variable will become reactive and available in the HTML.

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return { system: {
                CPU: {
                    avgload : ""
                }
             }
           }
  }
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Work as expected, so with this the created is not require anymore ?